# All possible ways to order numbers in an array with decreasing rows and columns

Tags: combinatorics

Given positive integer numbers $1,2,...,N\cdot M$. How many ways are there to order them in an $N\times M$ array given that the values decrease in each row from left to right and in each column from top to bottom? For small arrays one can just count but I don't find a general rule. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

This is the number of [standard Young tableaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau#Tableaux) for a Young diagram with $N$ rows and $M$ columns. By the [hook length formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula), this is

$$
\frac{(NM)!}{\prod_{i=1}^M\prod_{j=1}^N(i+j-1)}\;.
$$

This is [OEIS sequence A060854](https://oeis.org/A060854). That entry gives the alternative formula

$$
(NM)!\prod_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac{k!}{(M+k)!}\;.
$$

Comment: Yes! You're right!