# $(k^2)! \cdot \prod_{j = 0}^{k = 1} {{j!}\over{(j + k)!}}$ integer for $k \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

How do I see that for any positive integer $k$,$$(k^2)! \cdot  \prod_{j = 0}^{k = 1} {{j!}\over{(j + k)!}}$$is an integer?

Comment: Is the upper bound of the product supposed to be $k$?

Comment: I think the upper bound is $k-1$, and in that case you can use induction.

Comment: I suspect you mean something like this: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t177f6h1233195_trivial_extension . As the source field suggests, this is a particular case of the hook-length formula (namely, it counts the number of standard tableaux of a given rectangular shape).

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737865